# Not Sure About Wordpress Theme Settings

Tags: wordpress, themes

I am building a Wordpress theme for a small group of people. The concern that I have is if there will be any issues because of the differences in the users' settings. Say for instance, that one user, within his WP Reading settings has "Front page displays" set to latest posts, and another to a static page; as a theme designer, how would I ensure that there won't be any differences between how the theme works for different users?

I hope I've made it clear enough. If not, just let me know and I will elaborate.

Comment: Only an admin can make that change, that won't change on a user by user case.

Comment: Like I said I'm making the theme for several clients. All of them are admins. I am only supplying the theme.

Comment: Any ideas? I'm just worried that when another person installs the theme, he might have to change settings to get it to work properly; or am I just thinking about this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You could instruct the clients not to touch that area or it will break your theme **or** add the following to the css:

```
.options-reading-php .form-table tr:first-child 
{
    display: none;
}
```

The above should hide the `Front page displays` fields in the `Reading Settings` page.

Comment: Okay, I get that, but it's not really common practice is it? I don't think I really understand the whole concept of the settings. The WP reading settings are not exclusive to themes, right; they're global, if you will?